# Get the redirect url

Tags: objective-c

I have a url I know is going to redirect me to another destination:

```
url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%d/picture?type=normal", profile_id];
```

In this case, http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v1/yh/r/C5yt7Cqf3zU.jpg

How do I get the second url knowing the first one?

Comment: You seem to want `URL` from `NSURLResponse`

Comment: Use `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` of `NSURLConnection` and do as @devnull suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find by below code :

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    // cast the response to NSHTTPURLResponse so we can look for 404 etc
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    NSURL *url = [httpResponse URL];

    if ([httpResponse statusCode] >= 400) {
        // do error handling here
        NSLog(@"remote url returned error %d %@",[httpResponse statusCode],[NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode:[httpResponse statusCode]]);
    } else {
        // start recieving data
    }
}
```

Thanks.